# Show that the t-cube $Q_t$ is has connectivity t

Tags: graph-theory

The t-cube $Q_t$ may be defined as the graph whose vertices are all the binary $t$-tuples. Vertices are adjacent iff they differ in exactly one component. [e.g. in the 3-cube $(0,0,0)$ is adjacent to $(1,0,0) , (0,1,0) , (0,0,1)$]

I would like to show that $Q_t$ has connectivity $t$, that is there is no vertex cut of size less than $t$ which disconnects the graph. Please prove!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Menger's Theorem, it suffices to show that between any distinct vertices $u,v$, there are $t$ vertex-disjoint $u$-$v$-paths.

We proceed by induction on $t$. Clearly, it holds for $t=2$. Now, for larger $t$, let $u=(u_1,\dots,u_t),v=(v_1,\dots,v_t)$ be two distinct vertices. If $u_i=v_i$ for some $i$, then we can take $t-1$ vertex-disjoint $u$-$v$-paths in the $t-1$-dimensional subcube, and one more $u$-$v$-path $u,(u_1,\dots,1-u_i,\dots,u_t),P,(v_1,\dots,1-v_i,\dots,v_t),v$, where $P$ is a segment in another $t-1$-dimensional subcube.

If $u_i\neq v_i$ for all $i$, say $u=(0,\dots,0), v=(1,\dots,1)$. Then we can just take $u$-$v$-paths $u,w_{i,1},w_{i,2},\dots,w_{i,t-1},v$ ($i=1,\dots,t$), where $w_{i,j}$ has its $i$-th to $i+j-1$-th components value $1$, and $0$ otherwise, here we see the indices of components as in some cyclic group.

Comment: Great idea, thank you!